# Call new class but limit to 1 subclass via variable

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

I have a Class in my project that declares a few properties (Controls).

Along with these properties I have about 500 odd SubClasses that each populate their own set of properties.

I know its insane, right?

What I am trying to achieve is call a new instance of the main class while supplying a variable. This in turn will create only the subclass associated with the variable via a `Select Case` method, effectively avoiding loading 500 odd SubClasses with their default values into memory.

Below is my current Structure:

```
Public Class SysproBoVariables
    'Control Variables
    Public Property CTRL_ValidFlag As Boolean = False
    Public Property CTRL_StockType As String
    Public Property CTRL_SetupType As Char

    Public Property CustomerQuery As New ARSQRY
    Public Property SetupInvMaster As New INVSSTDOC
    Public Property SetupInvWarehouse As New INVSWSDOC
    Public Property PostJob As New WIPTJBDOC
    Public Property PostMaterialAllocations As New WIPTJMDOC
    '...Emagine another 495 of these...
End Class

'===========================================================================

Public Class ARSQRY
    'CustomerQuery Variables (ARSQRY)
    Public Property Customer As String = ""
    Public Property IncludeFutures As String = "N"
    Public Property IncludeTransactions As String = "N"
    '...Plus some more...
End Class

Public Class INVSSTDOC
    'SetupInvMaster Variables (INVSSTDOC)
    Public Property StockCode As String = ""
    Public Property Description As String = ""
    '...again add some more...
End Class

'...Continue the above 2 another 498 times...
```

I know this is overkill but is needed for the integration tools I am building

Below is the structure i am trying to build (I know the below illustrates something that will never be possible but is purely for clarity on what i need here) :

```
Public Class SysproBoVariables
    'Control Variables
    Public Property CTRL_ValidFlag As Boolean = False
    Public Property CTRL_StockType As String
    Public Property CTRL_SetupType As Char

    Public Sub New(ByRef Optional BoNameRef as string="")
        Select Case BoNameRef
            Case "ARSQRY"
                Public Property CustomerQuery As New ARSQRY '***
            Case "INVSSTDOC"
                Public Property SetupInvMaster As New INVSSTDOC '***
            Case "INVSWSDOC"
                Public Property SetupInvWarehouse As New INVSWSDOC '***
            '...Continue with this until all Subclasses are covered...
            Case Else
                '...Declare all Properties (Not Recommended)...
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
'....SublClasses goes here....
```

I know the *** areas are not possible but this is the process i hope to achieve

Any advice or critic welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize you already have an answer that you accepted, but in all honesty that pattern seems insane.  A simple interface coupled with a generic type will clean this mess up substantially.

First define an interface.  No implementation methods are needed as it is just a tool to enforce type constraints.

```
Public Interface IFred ' name is not important
    ' no implementation needed
End Interface
```

Now make `SysproBoVariables generic but constrained to the interface and replace all the data properties with a single property.  I also changed the data property to read-only as being able to assign a new instance seems strange considering your criteria.  You can change that back to read-write if needed.

```
Public Class SysproBoVariables(Of T As {IFred, New, Class})
    Public Sub New()
        DataProp = New T
    End Sub

    'Control Variables
    Public Property CTRL_ValidFlag As Boolean = False
    Public Property CTRL_StockType As String
    Public Property CTRL_SetupType As Char

    Public ReadOnly DataProp As T
End Class
```

Add the interface to the various class definitions.  Since there are no implementation methods or properties, this is painless.

```
Public Class ARSQRY : Implements IFred
    Public Property Customer As String = ""
    Public Property IncludeFutures As String = "N"
    Public Property IncludeTransactions As String = "N"
End Class

Public Class INVSSTDOC : Implements IFred
    Public Property StockCode As String = ""
    Public Property Description As String = ""
End Class
```

Now usage becomes clean and supports Intellisense checking.

```
Sub Example()
    Dim sbvARSQRY As New SysproBoVariables(Of ARSQRY)
    sbvARSQRY.DataProp.Customer = "Jim"

    Dim sbvINVSSTDOC As New SysproBoVariables(Of INVSSTDOC)
    sbvINVSSTDOC.DataProp.StockCode = "ABC"
    ' Intellisense will not allow the next line since INVSSTDOC does not have a Customer prop
    ' sbvINVSSTDOC.DataProp.Customer = "Jim" 
End Sub
```

---

Edit:  Since you expressed an uneasiness in using an interface, here is a version that uses a base class to achieve the same function.  It is just a design choice and I tend to prefer interfaces.

```
Public Class Base
    ' no implementation needed
End Class

Public Class SysproBoVariables(Of T As {Base, New})
    Public Sub New()
        DataProp = New T
    End Sub

    'Control Variables
    Public Property CTRL_ValidFlag As Boolean = False
    Public Property CTRL_StockType As String
    Public Property CTRL_SetupType As Char

    Public ReadOnly DataProp As T
End Class

Public Class ARSQRY : Inherits Base
    Public Property Customer As String = ""
    Public Property IncludeFutures As String = "N"
    Public Property IncludeTransactions As String = "N"
End Class

Public Class INVSSTDOC : Inherits Base
    Public Property StockCode As String = ""
    Public Property Description As String = ""
End Class
```

Comment: I will look into this in the morning (gmt+2). I have not worked with interfaces much but have seen them in action. It will be a big change and hill have a major impact on intellisense but would be very beneficial in the end. Thanks for the sample

Comment: @StevendeBeer, I added a class based example that achieve the same function.

Comment: You are da bomb. Your interface sample blew away the competition. Don't really care if i loose some rep over changing the selected answer as this gave me motivation on upgrading all my tools.

Comment: @StevendeBeer,   The primary lesson you should learn from this example is the usage of a generics and I don't want you to come away with the impression that this is the only way. The usage of the interface is just a way to limit the types of `SysproBoVariables` that can be created.  This is more of my design philosophy to limit access to a type than anything else.  If the signature is changed to `Public Class SysproBoVariables(Of T As {Class, New})` then the only constraints are that the type must be a `Class` and have a publicly accessible constructor (`Sub New).

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your Property declaration how it was in the top block, except without the New keyword and then populate the values of those properties in your constructor:

```
Public Class SysproBoVariables
    'Control Variables
    Public Property CTRL_ValidFlag As Boolean = False
    Public Property CTRL_StockType As String
    Public Property CTRL_SetupType As Char

    Public Property CustomerQuery As ARSQRY
    Public Property SetupInvMaster As INVSSTDOC
    Public Property SetupInvWarehouse As  INVSWSDOC
    Public Property PostJob As WIPTJBDOC
    Public Property PostMaterialAllocations As WIPTJMDOC

    Public Sub New(ByRef Optional BoNameRef as string="")
        Select Case BoNameRef
            Case "ARSQRY"
                CustomerQuery = New ARSQRY() '***
            Case "INVSSTDOC"
                SetupInvMaster = New INVSSTDOC() '***
            Case "INVSWSDOC"
                SetupInvWarehouse = New INVSWSDOC() '***
            '...Continue with this until all Subclasses are covered...
            Case Else
                '...Declare all Properties (Not Recommended)...
        End Select
    End Sub     

End Class
```

The other properties will just be Nothing unless the Case Else is reached.  If you need those other properties to populate when referenced you can do this:

```
Private m_CustomerQuery As ARSQRY

Public Property CustomerQuery As ARSQRY
    Get
        If m_CustomerQuery Is Nothing Then
            m_CustomerQuery = New ARSQRY
        End If

        Return m_CustomerQuery
    End Get
    Set(value As ARSQRY)
        m_CustomerQuery = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Out with the New in with the Answer. Thanks @N0Alias this saved me some digging. appreciate the snippets too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/341762/n0alias i changed my selected answer ast he changes  had no effect on intellisense. i know that was not originally requested but was part of the problem that i would have worked around at a later stage. Upvote though for keeping in-line with the original question as memory usage was brought down.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the up vote and I'm glad you got an answer.